# Parsing "" - Unrecognized escape sequence \T

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am trying to modify .config file. this line of code is only meant to be repleced in this file and few others with a new one from xml file but that goes later in code, currently I have issue with this line as I am not able to pass it to variable in a way that it will be treated as a regular string, will not be changed it in any way and will not throw "Parsing "" - Unrecognized escape sequence \T" exeption

I have always been doing it in this way if I don't need to use variables inside:

```
$oldValueSU = '<add key="splunk_username" value="${(splunk_username=D:\Tools\localtokens.xml)}"/>'
```

I also tried in this way

```
$oldValueSU = "<add key=""splunk_username"" value='`${(splunk_username=D:\Tools\localtokens.xml)}'/>"
```

None of these options work I am still receiving error "parsing "[Path I provided above]" - Unrecognized escape  sequence \T."

**How Script works:**
The script works in a way that it takes that variable and looks through the whole file in order to find a mathing one of it does then it takes a path to that file and adds it to other variable and then changes it's value to a diffrent string.

---

If more information is needed I will be happy to provide it

Comment: Use two backslashes instead of one to escape the backslash.

Comment: If I will do that the path will also change and will look like this 'D:\\Tools\\localtokens.xml' unless you have something diffrent in mind

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share relevant code snippet as well as a data sample (sanitized if necessary) and full error message.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to update an xml (config) file. Rule of thumb there is to use PowerShells XML capabilities instead of string methods like search and replace

Comment: Exactly right.  It is only the way it looks in the debugger.

Comment: I am trying to modify .config file. this line of code is only meant to be repleced in this file and few other with a new one from xml file but that goes later in code, currently I have issue with this line as I am not able to pass it to variable in a way that it will be treated as a regular string, will not change it in any way and will not throw "Parsing "" - Unrecognized escape sequence \T" exeption

Comment: *What* is producing "unrecognized escape sequence"? I can tell you it's not PowerShell, because the backslash is not an escape character in PowerShell. If you try your first expression on a PowerShell prompt, it will be echoed back to you exactly as you've specified.

Comment: It's powershell script stated in a jenkins job

Comment: Right -- so Jenkins (or part of it) is the one complaining, then, possibly because the script is fed to it in a string somehow with improper escaping, or because you got your levels crossed. Check how things are configured there. If possible, try a completely different way of executing the scripts that circumvents any possibility of something other than PowerShell reading the script. Again, if you open a PowerShell prompt and paste `$oldValueSU = '<add key="splunk_username" value="${(splunk_username=D:\Tools\localtokens.xml)}"/>'` into it, you'll get exactly what you asked for.

Comment: It's not jenkins fault, I just tested that you can replace any string with this one but you can't do it in the other way because you are getting this error. I never enconter such a problem before

Comment: Well it's not PowerShell's fault either, so you'll just have to look for the actual problem. If other people can't reproduce it (and I certainly cannot, using only a PowerShell prompt) they can't help. Consider adding details of how exactly you're configuring the Jenkins job and tagging `jenkins`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I found the issue and solution in my code

The issue was while trying to check if content of a file matches given string

```
if (($file -match $oldValueSU) -and ($file -match $oldValueSP))
```

It was using -match which uses Regex which was cousing the exeption I changed it to:

```
if (($file -like "*$oldValueSU*") -and ($file -like "*$oldValueSP*"))
```

After that in a part where in my code I was using -replace (which also uses Regex):

```
$fileContentPathTemp -replace "*$oldValueSU*", $newValueSU
```

I changed it to .Replace which works directly on String and it solved the issue:

```
$fileContentPathTemp.Replace($oldValueSU,$newValueSU)
```

### So the whole issue was based on using Regex this solution is more like a workaround which just does not use it at all

I hope this solution will help somebody in the future, I am sorry for not providing all of the nececary information at the beggining. Thanks everyone for spending time on my issue